# Plotting with lattice::wireframe()

Tags: r, 3d, lattice, wireframe

I wanted to use

```
 wireframe(z ~ x * y, shade = TRUE, scales=list(arrows=FALSE),xlab = "x", ylab = "y",zlab = "z")
```

Both x and y have range from 0 to 1. z however, is in the millions ($MM). I tried plotting and kept getting something like a 2-dimension surface plot on the bottom of the cube..I am suspecting that it's due to scaling? Do you have any tips on how to fix that? Thank you

Unfortunately i don't have enough reputation to post images..

Answer (score 1):

We don't need an image.  We need your source data.  But if in fact your "z" data range from zero to 1e6, with only a very few points have large values, then you'll get what you're describing.

Try setting the limits via the `zlim` argument to `wireframe` to a range that you believe captures the "interesting" portion of your data.

Another option is to plot `log(z)~x*y` , assuming all your z-values are greater than 1, or plotting `z^(.25)~x*y` .